# Read file from React Native bundle in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, react-native

Here's what I'm trying to solve:

**RN Structure**

```
|_ src
  |_ assets
    |_ files
      |_ file.mp3
```

**Objective C**

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(playMusic:(NSString*)filename)
{
  ....
}
```

**RN Code**

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
NativeModules.playMusic(fileName)
```

**Question**

How can I get the `fileName` to be the complete path of the file in order to read it from Objective C ?

The example is a little bit "easy" compared to what I'm trying to achieve and this is the only way it seems to work.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the bundle path using this call in Objective-C:

```
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
```

You'd just append your path to the end of that to get to the file.

But depending on your needs, you could use [RNFS](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) or similar package to do it in Javascript.

After submitting this I realized you're asking how to get to your RN files.   To do that, you'd need to make those files available in Xcode.  I've done it before by creating my own directory, e.g., "mybundle", and then copying that as a directory into Xcode.  (you can also create a soft link from android/app/src/main/assets) to make those same files available in Android.

Comment: The issue is that whenever I copy the files from RN to Objective C, the file path is being changed (due to compilation) and the folder reference is changing. I have files that read other file's content and this is where I'm loosing the reference and having the files not opening. I wanted to test if it's going to work if I get the path directly from RN instead of `NSBundle`

Comment: If you use the call above at runtime, it will always have the correct prefix.  Even from RN you'd need to get the the bundle prefix at runtime.  You can't hardcode the path.